Why the toast.success is not working here?
I want to show a toast using react-toastify package after succesfully deleting the data object. But the toast function is not working properly here.
import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify"

function RecipeRow({ recipe, recipes, setRecipes }) {
    const { id, title, image_link } = recipe

    const handleDeleteRecipe = (id) => {
        const proceedToDelete = window.confirm("Are you sure to delete the recipe?")
        if (proceedToDelete) {
            setRecipes(recipes.filter(r => r.id !== id))
            fetch(`http://localhost:3000/recipes/${id}`, {
                method: "DELETE",
                headers: {
                    "content-type": "application/json"
                },
            }).then(res => res.json())
                .then(() => {
                    toast.success("Recipe deleted!")
                    alert("recipe deleted")
                })
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return <>
        <ToastContainer autoClose={1000}></ToastContainer>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div className="flex items-center gap-3">
                    <div className="avatar">
                        <div className="mask mask-squircle w-12 h-12">
                            <img src={image_link} alt="Avatar Tailwind CSS Component" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                {title}
            </td>
            <td>
                <button className="btn btn-info text-white">Edit</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button onClick={() => handleDeleteRecipe(id)} className="btn btn-error text-white">Delete</button>
                <button onClick={() => {
                    const yes = window.confirm("yehnn")
                    if (yes) {

                        const showToast = () => {
                            toast.success("taosjjjjjj")
                        }
                        showToast()
                    }
                }}>Sho Toast</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </>

}
export default RecipeRow

I tried to show toast in the showToast() function, that was working perfectly. I also checked the function more than once.

you don't need nested then, try with async flow

Import css file in the top of the componenet
import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify"
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';


function RecipeRow({ recipe, recipes, setRecipes }) {
    const { id, title, image_link } = recipe

    const handleDeleteRecipe = (id) => {
        const proceedToDelete = window.confirm("Are you sure to delete the recipe?")
        if (proceedToDelete) {
            setRecipes(prevRecipes => prevRecipes.filter(r => r.id !== id));

  try {
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/recipes/${id}`, {
      method: "DELETE",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
    }

    const result = await response.json();
    console.log(result);

    toast.success("Recipe deleted!");
    alert("Recipe deleted");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error deleting recipe:', error);   
    toast.error("Failed to delete recipe.");
  }            
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return
<>
        <ToastContainer autoClose={1000} />
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div className="flex items-center gap-3">
                    <div className="avatar">
                        <div className="mask mask-squircle w-12 h-12">
                            <img src={image_link} alt="Avatar Tailwind CSS Component" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                {title}
            </td>
            <td>
                <button className="btn btn-info text-white">Edit</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button onClick={() => handleDeleteRecipe(id)} className="btn btn-error text-white">Delete</button>
                <button onClick={() => {
                    const yes = window.confirm("yehnn")
                    if (yes) {

                        const showToast = () => {
                            toast.success("taosjjjjjj")
                        }
                        showToast()
                    }
                }}>Sho Toast</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
   
</>

}
export default RecipeRow


you can improve the deleteRecipe  API method. and make sure to import the css
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

You won't need any nested then function where you don't use the response data. Try this
const handleDeleteRecipe = async id => {
    const proceedToDelete = window.confirm('Are you sure to delete the recipe?');
    if (proceedToDelete) {
        setRecipes(recipes.filter(r => r.id !== id));
        
        try{
            await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/recipes/${id}`, {
                method: 'DELETE',
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
            toast.success('Recipe deleted!');
        }catch(e){
            toast.success('Something went wrong while deleting!');
        }

    } else {
        return false;
    }
};

I've wrapped the fetch into try/catch for error handling, this will give nice user experience
